# jQuery validation for checkbox group

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Currently, I'm using jQuery validation plugin which activates with a simple required keyword inside the input field. But when I'm going to use this in a dynamically created checkbox field, it simply asked to check all checkboxes. But I want at least one checkbox needs to be checked.

```
 {% for opt in obj.option_array_a %}
      <label>
       <input class="optcheckbox" name="optcheckbox_{{ obj.question_number }}"
           id="{{ obj.id }}__{{ forloop.counter0 }}" type="checkbox"
        value="{{ opt }}"/> <span>{{ opt }}</span><br>
        </label>
   {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Search:  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery-validate%5D+one+checkbox

Comment: **Show us your actual rendered code**. That's likely because all of your checkboxes have a different name. Give them all the same name and the required rule will only make sure at least one is checked.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/7kdx4t6u/1/

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of how you can check if at least one checkbox is checked.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('input[name="question_1"]').change(function(){
    $('#result').text($('input[name="question_1"]:checked').length > 0 ? "OK" : "KO");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="question_1" value="answer 1" /> Answer 1
<input type="checkbox" name="question_1" value="answer 2" /> Answer 2
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mhasan09/vthfzas4/ found the solution